# How to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/MST1/ in n is 10^9

Tags: dynamic-programming, heuristics

Using Bottom to up DP approach, I am able to solve the problem How to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/MST1/ upto 10^8.

If input is very large n upto `10^9`. I will not be able to create lookup table for upto `10^9`. So what will be better approach to solve the problem ?

Is there any heuristic solution ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514471/how-to-use-dynamic-programming-number-of-distinct-function-call-is-too-large-as/22515235#22515235

Comment: post your solution in question

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int N_MAX = 20000001;
    int *DP = new int[N_MAX];
    DP[1] = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < N_MAX; i++) {
        int minimum =  DP[i - 1];
        if (i % 3 == 0) minimum = min(minimum, DP[i/3]);
        if (i % 2 == 0) minimum = min(minimum, DP[i/2]);

        DP[i] = minimum + 1;
    }

    int T, N; cin >> T;
    int c = 1;
    while (T--) {
        cin >> N;
        cout << "Case " << c++ << ": " << DP[N] << endl;
    }

    delete[] DP;
}
```

Comment: You did not read the question well enough!. If n is around 10^9, you will not be able to solve the question using dp table.