# How to check whether number is generated from the given number

Tags: algorithm

A set of numbers between 1-360 is given to me. An another number n is also given to me. I have to tell whether I can generate the given number n by the above list of number. I can do following operations on the given numbers

1. (a+b)mod 360
2. (a-b)mod 360 where a>b
3. I can take one number any number of time(even in a+b, a=b)

Now the goal is to detect whether I can generate the number n or not

Example suppose n is 60 and the list of number given is only 100(but it may be more), so i can generate 60 by adding 100 fifteen time and then take mod360 which is equal to 60.

Following is the solution that I have tried

```
#include<stdio.h>
int ispossible=0;
void AnglePossible(int a1[],int angle,int currentangle,int n)
{
    int i;
    if(angle==(currentangle%360))
        ispossible = 1;
    else if((currentangle!=0)&&(currentangle%360==0))
        return;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        AnglePossible(a1,angle,currentangle+a1[i],n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,k;
    int a1[361],a2[361];
    int i,j;
    int result;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a1[i]);
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a2[i]);

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        ispossible=0;
        AnglePossible(a1,a2[i],0,n);
        if(ispossible==1)
        printf("YES\n");
        else
        printf("NO\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you just given a single `n`, or are you given many? Do you have any performance requirements? Can you show us your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: @dukeling n is a number that I have to check whether it can be generated with the following given list of numbers by applying the above rules. yes i have tried to solve this and I am editing the question for that but my solution is not correct 100%

Comment: Can you give more test cases? I have a naive algorithm, but I dont know if it covers all the cases

Comment: here is a hint: say you are given {a1, a2,..,an} & number X to reach to. You can get to any multiple of GCD(a1,360), GCD(a2,360),.., GCD(an, 360).

Comment: @pirate from where I should look into this kind of things....... Is there are some specific books for that.

Comment: @pirate GCD is dealing with only a1 and 360 but I can also add two number. How it's taking the advantage of adding/subtracting of  two numbers.Should I have to again add and subtract the GCD and again find the GCD.I think some other nice trick is also there.

Comment: just keep solving the problem and dn't stop until you figure out everything about the problem.   Your range is low, you can only get 360 numbers in the beginning, if you can do addition with only two numbers & subtraction between two numbers, do them first & store the numbers you get in bit map. then apply gcd logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive algorithm that solves(i think) this problem, but probably not the most efficient one.

Problem setup:

Input:

1. **nums** (numbers. an array of ints)
2. **target** (the target)

Output:

- bool indicating if **target** is reachable

Essentially you want to get to **target** by using **nums**. Your starting point is **0** on the number line (you can always get to **0**).

Therefore, you keep track of the locations you can get to (an array initialized to `[0]`). For each number in **nums**, you update the locations that you can get to with this new number. Since additions and substractions are commutative, the order is not important.

Here is a small python program showing this idea:

```
def reachable(i, start = 0): 
  cantReach = range(360)
  canReach = set()
  reach = start
  while reach in cantReach:
    cantReach.remove(reach)
    canReach.add(reach)
    reach += i
    reach = reach % 360 
  return canReach

def main(nums, target):
  canReach = set([0])
  for i in nums:
    for j in canReach:
      canReach = canReach.union(reachable(i, j)) 

  canReach = sorted(list(canReach))
  print "can reach:", canReach
  print "result:", target in canReach


main([100],60)
```

The output is:

```
can reach: [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260, 280, 300, 320, 340]
result: True
```

Comment: @aha... I don't know python... I am c,C++ programmer. could you please explain what logic you have implemented.